# cross-browser integration testing of Ember.js views with 3rd party plugins

Tags: javascript, ember.js, integration-testing

We have inplace fields in our app, including some that depend on jQuery plugins like date picker or select2. They update data on focus out or enter.

The problem I'm facing now is that the one extended of Select2 works in Chrome but won't in IE11 or IE10 because different events are propagated.

Changing one thing can break control in IE as we had when we rewrote `setTimeout` to `Em.run.later`.

I'm interested in testing such controls where a lot of asynchrony can be used. Testing it cross-browser would be another help.

Do you have any experience with cross-browser integration testing of real-live application written in Ember.js / Ember-Data? I'm curious how Discourse solved this.